# Django parse XML from a POST

Tags: python, django

I'm receiving an HTTP POST. With one parameter thats sent: **xml**

It  contain an xml document. The format of this document is:

```
 <?xml version="1.1" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <delivery_receipt>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <status>Delivered</status>
</delivery_receipt>
```

I need to get whats in `<status>` from the POST, how do I parse the parameter and get the 'status'?

**Update....**

if request.POST:

```
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
from lxml.etree import fromstring

h = fromstring(request.POST['xml'])
h.cssselect('delivery_reciept status').text_content()
```

I'm not sure that  request.POST['xml'] will work tho

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/ULtbRwf2cdo

Comment: Did you try to do anything yourself before asking?

Comment: I'm look to know where to start @wRAR lxml seems perfect

Comment: @Spike you should start at Google.

Comment: @wRAR updated question with what I have now tried based on Droogans answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should) use CSS selectors with XML documents, granted you are doing relatively simple tasks for parsing XML documents. CSS selectors are clear, easy to read and write, and are more expressive than XPATH queries.

I suggest getting [lxml](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) installed, and using their [cssselect](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) features.

Your end result might look like this:

```
>>> h = fromstring("""<?xml version="1.1" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <delivery_receipt>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <status>Delivered</status>
    </delivery_receipt> """)
>>> h.cssselect('delivery_reciept status').text_content()
```

Comment: I added the link to lxml for Windows, since it's difficult to get set up with. The Linux version of this library is as simple as `pip install lxml`.

Comment: so would that be fromstring(request.POST[xml]) ?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. How much xml are you parsing in this project? lxml is a pretty big library, and may not be worth the trouble for one little 'ol xml parse. Python has a (somewhat awkward) built in xml parsing library, [minidom](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

Comment: First and only xml parse for this project